# SELECT command denied to user '<userid>'@'<my-pc-ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I get this error when I'm using post man for get response from my API.

```
   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user '<userid>'@'<my-pc-ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
```

but I can use SELECT Statement perfectly in Workbench with the same user.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://<database.ip>:3306/<database.schema>
spring.datasource.username = test
spring.datasource.password = test123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I'm trying to using root account but I get this error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException : Unknown database '<db_name>'
```

I can solve this issue with this

1. replace

@Table (table = "tablename") instead

@Table(table = "tablename", catalog = "catalogname" schema)

2. place this thing to application.properties

   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: Usually this is because you have not granted access to your ip address. https://www.copahost.com/blog/grant-mysql-remote-access/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli But why I can query in workbench, I try to login root account and I can query too

Comment: In that case the user test is not granted

Comment: I can solve it now.

Comment: I'm happy to help. I added my comment as the answer and would appreciate it if you would accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user "test" is not granted to access the database.

You have to grant it first

Please find the grant command in the manual
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

Just like Simon says above, the user 'test' doesn't have the right privileges to perform a 'SELECT' operation.